# Como recuperar o retorno de uma função que foi executada dentro de uma Thread em Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread, multithreading

Estou precisando executar uma função através de uma Thread só que eu não estou sabendo como faço para recuperar o retorno desta função. Abaixo um exemplo de como eu quero fazer:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def teste_thread():
  for k in range(5):
    print('Executando Thread')
    time.sleep(1)

  return 'Thread Executada com sucesso!' #Como faço para pegar esse retorno de função?


t = Thread(target=teste_thread)
t.start()

print('Isso foi colocado depois do inicio da Thread')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar `multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool` ao invés de `from threading import Thread` nessa sua implementação? Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import time

pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)

def teste_thread():
  for k in range(5):
    print('Executando Thread')
    time.sleep(1)
  return 'Thread Executada com sucesso!'

def exec():
    async_call = pool.apply_async(teste_thread)
    print('Processando....')
    return async_call.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(exec())
```

Adicionei o trecho '**main**' para conseguir simular a chamada à sua operação.

Comment: Sua solução resolveu o meu problema, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Fico feliz em saber que pude ajudar. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode, ao invés de retornar algo com o `return`, criar um atributo da função, que possa servir como retorno, por exemplo:

```
def teste_thread():
  for k in range(5):
    print('Executando Thread')
    time.sleep(1)

  teste_thread.retorno = 'Thread Executada com sucesso!'
```

Note que o início do nome da variável `retorno` é prescedido pelo nome da função `teste_thread`

Dessa forma, quando você estartar a thread `t.start()`, esse atributo ficará disponível como `teste_thread.retorno` no memso escopo em que a thread for iniciada.

Exemplo completo:

```
from threading import Thread
import time


def teste_thread():
  for k in range(5):
    print('Executando Thread')
    time.sleep(1)

  teste_thread.retorno = 'Thread Executada com sucesso!' #Como faço para pegar esse retorno de função?


t = Thread(target=teste_thread)
t.start()


# O JOIN ESPERA THREAD TERMINAR SUA EXECUÇÃO
# SE VOCÊ QUISER PROSEGUIR O CÓDIGO REMOVENDO O JOIN
# PODE ADICIONAR UM TRY EXCEPTION PRA VERIFICAR SE A FUNÇÃO 
# JÁ TEM O ATRIBUTO RETORNO ANTES DE TENTAR PRINTAR

t.join()
print(teste_thread.retorno)
```